# Combine two similar rows in DataTable into one

Tags: c#, datatable

Is there any way to combine two cells and turn them into one (not the view, but rather the cells)? e.g.

Before:

```
ID  |  Item  |  Unit Price  |  Qty
-------------------------------
8     Pasta    $20             1 

9     Pasta    $20             1
```

After:

```
ID  |  Item  |  Unit Price  |  Qty
-------------------------------
8     Pasta    $20             2
```

my code below, is not the same on above, it only changes the value of quantity and addAmnt. and after the statement continues, DT should have two rows not one.

```
if (TransactionControl.SelectedTable == TransactionTypes.Edit)
{
    bool[] bb = new bool[]
    {
        true,  //while
        true,  //Row Count = 0 & 1
        false  //Merge
    };

    Int32 origProductID = Convert.ToInt32(TransDetailDT.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
    decimal origQty = Convert.ToDecimal(TransDetailDT.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);
    decimal origSRP = Convert.ToDecimal(TransDetailDT.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value);
    decimal addAmnt = TransactionControl.AddAmt;

    DataTable DT;
    do
    {
        DT = tblTransactionDetailTA.GetTDetail(TransactionControl.TransactionID, Convert.ToInt32(TransDetailDT.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value), addAmnt);
        if(bb[1] && DT.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            tblTransactionDetailTA.UpdateSingleItem(Convert.ToDecimal(TransactionControl.Qty), addAmnt, origQty, origProductID, origSRP, TransactionControl.TransactionID);
            bb[1] = false;
            bb[2] = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(bb[1] && DT.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            DataRow DR = DT.Rows[0];
            DR["Quantity"] = numQty.Value;
            DR["SpecialPrice"] = addAmnt;

            DR.EndEdit();
            tblTransactionDetailTA.Update(DR);

            bb[1] = false;
            bb[2] = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (bb[2] && DT.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            DT.Rows[0]["Quantity"] = Convert.ToDouble(DR1["Quantity"]) + 
            Convert.ToDouble(DR2["Quantity"]);
            DT.Rows[1].Delete();
            tblTransactionDetailTA.Update(DT);
            bb[0] = false;
        }
        else { bb[0] = false; MessageBox.Show("false"); }
    }
    while (bb[0]);
    qryTransactionDetailTA.Fill(litePOSDataSet.qryTransactionDetail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want well, I think you want to do something like this:

```
// Below is for my sample data
var dt = new DataTable();
var idCol = dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
var itemCol = dt.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
var upCol = dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price", typeof(int));
var qtyCol = dt.Columns.Add("Qty",typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(8, "Pasta", 20, 1);
dt.Rows.Add(9, "Pasta", 20, 1);

// I generate my expected result by using linq
var mergedData = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(g=> g.ItemArray[itemCol.Ordinal])
    .Select(c=> new
    {
        item = c.Key,
        id = c.FirstOrDefault()?[idCol],                    // I think you need first id as result
        up = c.Average(x=> int.Parse(x[upCol].ToString())), // I think you need average of Unit Prices as result
        qty = c.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[qtyCol].ToString()))   // I think you need sum of Quantity as result
    });

// A clone of current DataTable will give me its structure without data
// I use this as a temporary DataTable
var newDt = dt.Clone();
foreach (var md in mergedData)
{
    newDt.Rows.Add(md.id, md.item, md.up, md.qty);
}

dt = newDt;
```